# Why is XMLHttpRequest not working?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have tried installing XMLHttpRequest using npm and also attached this code snippet to make it work:

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
var myRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

When I debugged it, it(the console of google chrome) says "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined"

:( please help!

UPDATE:
When I simply wrote this code:

var myRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

It didnt work then I researched for it and saw that installing this npm package which I mentioned above, would work. By doing so, the error(mentioned above) popped up. So telling to say that either of the code for XMLHttpRequest is not working at all.

Comment: Node.js is not (and has nothing to do with) browser Javascript.

Comment: Either don't use `require()` or use a bundler.

Comment: @SLaks FYI this is an npm package for node js https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmlhttprequest

Comment: Require is not a part of js

Comment: you have to run it via node js. directly running in chrome won't work

Comment: @SagarV: That still has nothing to do with browser Javascript.

Comment: agree. please see my second comment

Comment: Yeah sorry, I thought it could be having some relation with nodejs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use XMLHttpRequest in Google Chrome: Then just use it. It is [built into the browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest). You are getting an error because [`require` is a Node.js feature](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require).

If you want to use XMLHttpRequest in Node.js: Then you need to run your script (which `require`s it) with Node.js and not through a webpage loaded into Google Chrome.

To run it in Node.js, type the command:

```
node filename.js
```

Comment: But I want to use it in my app.js section to write some code with it.

Comment: @ShoaibSivany — Why "but"? Just do that. (following the notes above depending on if app.js runs under node.js or Chrome)

Comment: I think I didnt get you. You are telling me to write this in my node application console? I did but got an error. I am new to nodejs exe btw.

Comment: "You are telling me to write this in my node application console?" — No. You mentioned `app.js`. Either you are running that with Node.js or with Chrome. There isn't enough information to tell which. Determine which of the two it is, then write code according to the instructions in the first two lines of this answer in app.js.

Comment: "I did but got an error" — *an error* is too vague to be useful. When you ask a question you need a [mcve] and a **clear problem statement**. You should quote error messages.

Comment: Alright alright. Look I am getting started with JSON and I copied the JavaScript code to do some practice in my VS Code. I am working in index.html and app.js only. When I code in app.js, I run index.html in chrome and see the results to understand it clearly. Today I saw the bunch of code which takes text from another website using the XMLHttpRequest thing. I copied it and pasted it in my app.js file. I then ran the index.html file which is connected to my app.js file, but nothing worked. So I opened my vscode and debugged there and saw the error that XMLHttpRequest is not defined.

Comment: I researched for it and then installed npm XMLHttpRequest  in command then I again ran my index file but this time I got an error in my chrome console "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined". So I came here and questioned.

Comment: OK. So you are **not using Node**. You are using **Chrome**. See the first paragraph of this answer. Forget about npm. Forget about require.

Comment: "So I opened my vscode and debugged there and saw the error that XMLHttpRequest is not defined" — It sounds like when you tried to debug your code because it didn't work in Chrome, you tried to run it in Node and use the VS Node Debugger. Don't do that. Use the debugger built into Chrome.